# Disable the default app key (super+num) functionality on Ubuntu 17.10 and later

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I like to switch workspaces via <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd>. But unfortunately the default behavior in Ubuntu for <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> is to select applications from the dock.

Is it possible to disable that functionality? I've tried overriding the keyboard shortcuts but it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: this works for Debian: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510376/195308

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### For Ubuntu 17.10 - 18.10

Run the following command in Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
```

This should disable the default behaviour of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd>.

Comment: This has frustrated me to no end, thank you very much!

Comment: In 19.04 this no longer seems to work. I've even uninstalled the default dock and it still switches, so it seems to be handled somewhere else.

Comment: @per See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1137705/480481

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS—thank you!

Answer (score 27):

#### For Ubuntu 19.04

In addition to [Nolf's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1137705/), you can also set these settings on the command line with these commands:

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-1 []
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-2 []
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-3 []
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-4 []
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-5 []
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-6 []
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-7 []
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-8 []
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-9 []
```

**Update:**

I'm using [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) now (instead of [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/)) and got the same problem back again. Now we need these commands:

```bsh
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/hot-keys false
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/hotkey-prefix-text "''"

dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-1 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-2 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-3 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-4 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-5 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-6 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-7 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-8 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-9 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-10 "['']"

dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-kp-1 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-kp-2 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-kp-3 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-kp-4 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-kp-5 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-kp-6 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-kp-7 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-kp-8 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-kp-9 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-hotkey-kp-10 "['']"

dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-1 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-2 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-3 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-4 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-5 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-6 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-7 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-8 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-9 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-10 "['']"

dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-kp-1 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-kp-2 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-kp-3 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-kp-4 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-kp-5 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-kp-6 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-kp-7 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-kp-8 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-kp-9 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-ctrl-hotkey-kp-10 "['']"

dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-1 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-2 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-3 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-4 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-5 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-6 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-7 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-8 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-9 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-10 "['']"

dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-kp-1 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-kp-2 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-kp-3 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-kp-4 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-kp-5 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-kp-6 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-kp-7 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-kp-8 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-kp-9 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/app-shift-hotkey-kp-10 "['']"
```

And then turn off and on the extension should make it work.

Comment: `for i in $(seq 1 9); do gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-${i} []; done`

Comment: `for i in $(seq 1 9); do gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-${i} '[]'; done` (missing quotes around [])

Comment: works for 20.04

Answer (score 13):

#### For Ubuntu 19.04

Install `dconf-editor` (`sudo apt install dconf-editor`) and open `dconf-editor`. Replace the keyboard shortcuts with empty brackets '`[]`' as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of how this is done for supr+5 keyboard shortcut]

Comment: This works, but the path on 19.04 is `/org/gnome/shell/keybindings/`, at least for me.

Comment: @PerJohansson, you saved my time, thank you. I found out that `/org/gnome/shell/keybindings/` has priority over `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/`

Answer (score 7):

**For Ubuntu 20.04.4**
This was enough:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
for i in $(seq 1 9); do gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-${i} '[]'; done
```

credits to:
[@gitaarik](https://askubuntu.com/users/230971/gitaarik) and [@Bibek Shrestha](https://askubuntu.com/users/15856/bibek-shrestha) in:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1138322/389523

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 22.04 as of March 2023.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience on Ubuntu 19.04 I have to set **both**

```
org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-1 '[]'
org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-1 '[]'
```

in order to deactivate the app launcher shortcut 1. If I change only one of the two settings it does not work.

Comment: Yup. Looks like Ubuntu 20.04 works the same way. You've got to change *both* of them to change the behavior. Thanks! This was driving me crazy.