# Use Super+<Number> to switch workspaces in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I would like to set up Ubuntu to switch between workspaces when pressing Super+Number (ie: Super+1 goes to workspace 1, etc etc)

I have the correct shortcuts set in the Keyboard settings, but instead of switching workspaces it opens up the app from the drawer on the left. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to disable the default Super+Number shortcut in 16.04.

There's been multiple post and links I've found regarding much older installs of Ubuntu (12.XX~ish), they recommend modifying compizconfig, but I don't know if that's still relevant to 16.04.

Additionally, I found another question regarding 17.10: [Disable the app key (super+num) default functionality in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968103/disable-the-app-key-supernum-default-functionality-in-ubuntu-17-10)

However, the suggestion there to try `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false` returns `No such schema 'org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock'`

Any help that anyone can offer would be a huge help!

Comment: Compiz is still relevant to 16.04. I believe it's not used on 17.10.