# Disable default dock app shortcut (super+num) functionality on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, 19.04

I would like to disable the functionality of using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd> to open applications residing in the Dock, so that I can use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd> solely for switching workspaces.

*From Ubuntu 17.10 up until, and including, Ubuntu 18.10, this could be disabled using:*

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
```

(see [Disable the default app key (super+num) functionality on Ubuntu 17.10 and later](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968103/disable-the-default-app-key-supernum-functionality-on-ubuntu-17-10-and-later))

After updating to Ubuntu 19.04, **this solution does no longer work** for me.

How can I achieve the same thing in Ubuntu 19.04?